# Display Add-AppxPackage progressbar at bottom console window

Tags: powershell, console, progress-bar

In PowerShell v5.0, how can I display the Add-AppxPackage's cmdlet progressbar at the bottom console window instead of this?:

[image]

The progress-bar is hiding information output that I wrote at the start / top of the console.

I asked this question to ChatGPT AI and it was unable to understand the problem.

This is the full code that I'm using (almost all of this code it was generated by ChatGPT):

```
# AppX Automated Package Installer

# Takes a string input of an AppX package name and parses it to extract the name, version, architecture, and publisher ID. 
# It uses regular expressions to match the package string pattern and returns a custom object with the parsed information. 
# If the input string cannot be parsed, an error is thrown.
function Get-PackageInfo {
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string]$PackageString
    )

    $dirname = [System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($PackageString)
    if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($dirname)) {
        $dirname = $PWD
    }

    $filename = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileName($PackageString) -replace "(?i)\.Appx$", ""

    $regex = '^(?<Name>.+?)_(?<Version>.+?)_(?<Architecture>.+?)__(?<PublisherId>.+)$'
    $match = $filename -match $regex

    if (!$match) {
        throw "Unable to parse the string package: '$PackageString'"
    }

    $packageName = $matches['Name']
    $packageVersion = $matches['Version']
    $packageArchitecture = $matches['Architecture']
    $packagePublisherId = $matches['PublisherId']
    $packageFullName = "${packageName}_${packageVersion}_${packageArchitecture}__${packagePublisherId}"
    $packageFullPath = [System.IO.Path]::Combine($dirname, "$filename.Appx")

    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Name = $packageName
        Version = $packageVersion
        Architecture = $packageArchitecture
        PublisherId = $packagePublisherId
        FullName = $packageFullName
        FullPath = $packageFullPath
    }
}

$packageString = "Microsoft.VP9VideoExtensions_1.0.52781.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe.Appx"
$sourcePackage = Get-PackageInfo -PackageString $packageString


Write-Output "Source Package Info:"
Write-Output "Package String.....: $packageString"
Write-Output "Package Full Path..: $($sourcePackage.FullPath)"
Write-Output "Full Name..........: $($sourcePackage.FullName)"
Write-Output "Name...............: $($sourcePackage.Name)"
Write-Output "Version............: $($sourcePackage.Version)"
Write-Output "Architecture.......: $($sourcePackage.Architecture)"
Write-Output "Publisher Id.......: $($sourcePackage.PublisherId)"
Write-Output ""

Write-Output "Checking if source package it is already installed..."
Write-Output ""
$packages = Get-AppxPackage "$($sourcePackage.Name)*" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
foreach ($package in $packages) {
    if ($package.Version -eq $sourcePackage.Version -and $package.Architecture -eq $sourcePackage.Architecture) {
        Write-Warning "Source package $($sourcePackage.Name) v$($sourcePackage.Version) ($($sourcePackage.Architecture)) is already installed."
        Write-Warning "Installation is not needed."
        Write-Output ""
        Write-Output "Program will terminate now. Press any key to exit..."
        $Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey("NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown")
        Exit 0
    }
}

Write-Output "Source package $($sourcePackage.Name) v$($sourcePackage.Version) ($($sourcePackage.Architecture)) is ready to be installed."
Write-Output ""

Write-Output "Installing source package..."
Write-Output ""
try {
    Add-AppxPackage -Path "$($sourcePackage.FullPath)" -ErrorAction Stop
    Write-Host "The source package $($sourcePackage.Name) v$($sourcePackage.Version) ($($sourcePackage.Architecture)) has been successfully installed." -BackgroundColor Black -ForegroundColor Green 
    Write-Output ""
    Write-Output "Program will terminate now. Press any key to exit..."
    $Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey("NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown")
    Exit 0
}
catch {
    Write-Host "Error installing source package $($sourcePackage.Name) v$($sourcePackage.Version) ($($sourcePackage.Architecture))"  -BackgroundColor Black -ForegroundColor Red
    Write-Output ""
    Write-Output ""
    Write-Error -Message ($_.Exception | Format-List * -Force | Out-String)
    Write-Output ""
    Write-Output "Program will terminate now. Press any key to exit..."
    $Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey("NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown")
    Exit 1
}
```

Comment: This is by design, you can hide the progress bar with `$ProgressPreference = 'Ignore'` before running the other code.

Comment: @Santiago Squarzon Thanks for the tip, it is very useful as a workaround. However, there is no viable solution to still show the progressbar but just force to show it in the correct console coordinates?.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of unless you're looking to implement your own progress own instead of the cmdlet.

Comment: You could however add vertical padding to your function's output so it doesn't overlap with the progress bar (simply output a few empty strings before producing the actual output)

Comment: Just an FYI: In [_PowerShell (Core) 7+_](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md), the default progress bar style (selectable via `$PSStyle.Progress`) is now a minimal in-line display that doesn't obscure any existing information.

Comment: As an aside: I don't know which parts ChatGPT contributed, but this is pretty un-idiomatic PowerShell code.

Comment: @mklement0 Maybe. I'm not an expert on PS, but once I requested ChatGPT to optimize and simplify my "final" code, it replaced the bunch of "Write-*" with Format-Table, the RegEx simplified to a "-split", the code where I try to determine whether the AppX is installed I moved it to a function body and ChatGPT used a one-liner pipe with "Where-Object", and I'm satisfied with all that, although the code needed a lot of refactor from my side because ChatGPT is constantly adding things that I can't use in PS v5, and I don't have enough knowledge to detect them until I run the code to get errors.

Answer (score 0):

Feel free to publish other answer different than this, to mark it as the accepted one.

---

This is just an update of the code, with @Santiago Squarzon's workaround applied:

```
# --------------------------------------------- #
# AppX Automated Package Installer - by Elektro #
# --------------------------------------------- #

# This script will find any AppX package files within the current directory (without recursion),
# print info about the package, print a message in case of the package is already installed,
# and install the package in case of it is not installed, handling errors during installation.

# ---------------------------------------------------------------------

# Takes a string argument that points to an AppX package name or file,
# then it uses a regular expression to match the package string pattern
# and returns a custom object with the Name, Version, Architecture,
# PublisherId and other properties.
#
# Parameters:
#   -PackageString: A string that points to the file name
#                   or full path of an AppX package file.
#
# Returns:
#   A PSCustomObject object with these properties defined:
#     [String] Name
#     [String] Version
#     [String] Architecture
#     [String] PublisherId
#     [String] FullName
function Get-AppXPackageInfo {
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [string]$PackageString
    )

    #$dirname = [System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($PackageString)
    #if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($dirname)) {
    #    $dirname = $PWD
    #}

    $filename = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileName($PackageString) -replace "(?i)\.Appx$", ""

    $regex = '^(?<Name>.+?)_(?<Version>.+?)_(?<Architecture>.+?)__(?<PublisherId>.+)$'
    $match = $filename -match $regex

    if (!$match) {
        throw "Unable to parse the string package: '$PackageString'"
    }

    [string]$packageName         = $matches['Name']
    [string]$packageVersion      = $matches['Version']
    [string]$packageArchitecture = $matches['Architecture']
    [string]$packagePublisherId  = $matches['PublisherId']
    [string]$packageFullName     = "${packageName}_${packageVersion}_${packageArchitecture}__${packagePublisherId}"
    #[string]$packageFullPath    = [System.IO.Path]::Combine($dirname, "$filename.Appx")

    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Name = $packageName
        Version = $packageVersion
        Architecture = $packageArchitecture
        PublisherId = $packagePublisherId
        FullName = $packageFullName
        #FullPath = $packageFullPath
    }
}

# Determines whether an Appx package matching the specified
# name, version and architecture is installed in the system.
#
# Parameters:
#   -Name........: The package name.
#   -Version.....: The package version.
#   -Architecture: The package architecture ("x86", "x64").
#
# Returns:
#   $true if the AppX package is installed in the system,
#   $false otherwise.
function IsAppxPackageInstalled() { 
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [string]$name,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [string]$version,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [string]$architecture
    )

    $packages = Get-AppxPackage "$($name)*" -ErrorAction Stop | Where-Object { 
        $_.Name.ToLower()              -eq $name.ToLower()         -and 
        $_.Version.ToLower()           -eq $version.ToLower()      -and 
        "$($_.Architecture)".ToLower() -eq $architecture.ToLower()
    }
    return ($packages.Count -gt 0)
}

# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

$host.ui.RawUI.WindowTitle = "AppX Automated Package Installer - by Elektro"

# Hides the progress-bar of 'Add-AppxPackage' cmdlet for this script.
# Thanks to @Santiago Squarzon for the tip: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75716867
$ProgressPreference = "Ignore"

Do {
    Clear-Host
    Write-Output " * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * "
    Write-Output ""
    Write-Output " AppX Automated Package Installer - by Elektro "
    Write-Output ""
    Write-Output " * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * "
    Write-Output ""
    Write-Output " This script will find any AppX package files within the current directory (without recursion),"
    Write-Output " print info about the package, print a message in case of the package is already installed,"
    Write-Output " and install the package in case of it is not installed, handling errors during installation."
    Write-Output " _________________________________________________________________"
    Write-Output ""
    Write-Host "-Continue? (Y/N)"
    $key = $Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey("NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown")
    $char = $key.Character.ToString().ToUpper()
} while ($char -ne "Y" -and $char -ne "N")

if ($char -eq "N") {Exit 1} 
Clear-Host

$appxFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path "$PWD" -Filter "*.appx"

if ($appxFiles.Count -eq 0) {
    Write-Warning "No Appx files were found in the current directory."
    Write-Output ""
    $LastExitCode = 2
} else {
    $appxFiles | ForEach-Object {
        # The AppX package string. It can be a file name (with or without extension), or a full path.
        $packageString = $_.FullName
        $packageInfo = Get-AppXPackageInfo -PackageString $packageString
        $nameVerArch = "$($packageInfo.Name) v$($packageInfo.Version) ($($packageInfo.Architecture))"
        Write-Host "Package Info.:" -ForegroundColor Gray
        Write-Host ($packageInfo | Format-List | Out-String).Trim() -ForegroundColor DarkGray
        Write-Output ""

        $isInstalled = IsAppxPackageInstalled -Name $packageInfo.Name -Version $packageInfo.Version -Architecture $packageInfo.Architecture
        if ($isInstalled) {
            Write-Warning "Package $nameVerArch is already installed."
            Write-Warning "Installation is not needed."
        } else {
            Write-Output "Package $nameVerArch is ready to install."
            Write-Output "Installing package..."
            try {
                Add-AppxPackage -Path "$($_.FullName)" -ErrorAction Stop
                Write-Host "Package $nameVerArch has been successfully installed." -BackgroundColor Black -ForegroundColor Green 
            } catch {
                Write-Host "Error installing package $nameVerArch" -BackgroundColor Black -ForegroundColor Red
                Write-Output ""
                Write-Error -Message ($_.Exception | Format-List * -Force | Out-String)
                $LastExitCode = 1
                Break
            }
        }
        Write-Output ""
        $LastExitCode = 0
    }
}

Write-Output "Program will terminate now with exit code $LastExitCode. Press any key to exit..."
$Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey("NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown")
Exit $LastExitCode
```